# Add minutes to a time format in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm building a really simple application in Android Studio where I inform a current time (HH:MM), a distance in meters and a velocity in meters per minute, then I need to calculate the time (distance / velocity) and the result, in minutes, add in the time variable. For example:

```
time = "01:45:15" // hour, minute, seconds, user input
distance = 45 // meters, user input
velocity = 30 // meters per minute, user input

newTime = "01:46:45" // Because it took a minute and a half (45/30)
```

I looked online and found some solutions, and my current code is (i'm VERY new to Kotlin):

```
var distance = edTrecho.text.toString()
var velocity = edVelocidade.text.toString()
var minutes = distance.toLong() / velocity.toLong()
var df = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(edTime.text.toString())
var calendar = GregorianCalendar()

calendar.time = df
calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, minutes)
var newTime = calendar.time
```

But the `add` method can add only integer values, i would need to add a decimal value for minutes (E.g.: 1,5 minutes should add a minute and 30 seconds)

What is the best way to accomplish this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use seconds in your calculations, like:

```
var seconds = (distance.toDouble() / (velocity.toDouble() / 60)).roundToInt()
```

you must convert to `Double` to avoid integer division and finally round to integer with `roundToInt()`.
`velocity.toDouble() / 60` is the velocity converted to **m/sec**.

and add them:

```
calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, seconds)
```

Comment: Output exactly as expected, and a simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add non-integer values for minutes - just convert them to seconds and add seconds. Or milliseconds if you need to be more precise. It's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert minutes into seconds and add them and then again convert back them to minutes to get the desired result.

```
var seconds = minutes * 60;
calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, seconds);
var total_minutes = calendar.time/60;
```